# legit TS type declaration

Tags: typescript, types, vuejs3

Working on Vue-3 project with TS support. Where I have declared a variable `const myVariable = ref()`.

In another block of function, I have declared a variable this way

`const response: typeof myVariable.value = [];`

My concern is that would it be valid? There are other ways though. Just a little curious about this statement.

Comment: "*My concern is that would it be valid?*" does it compile?

Comment: @VLAZ yes, it does.

Comment: Then it's valid.